# jQuery Mobile: Adding close button at end of a custom select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to add a button to close the select menu at its end so for a very long select menu you do not have to scroll back to the top.

It could look like "Close this menu" here: http://jsfiddle.net/es0mxd3s/2/

Also I know already how to center this, but the changes get lost with every select of an option:

```
$('#company_characteristics-menu .ui-last-child a').removeClass('ui-btn-icon-right ui-checkbox-on').attr("style", "text-align: center");
```

Is there any clever way to have this close button at the end and I am just missing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this?

```
$(document).on("click",".ui-last-child",function(){
$(".ui-icon-delete").click();
})
```

and this is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/es0mxd3s/3/).

Comment: I added something like the following to uncheck the last option:

    $("#company_characteristics .close_option").removeAttr("selected");
    $("#company_characteristics").selectmenu("refresh", true);

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function() {
  $(".ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-icon-delete").removeClass("ui-btn-left");
  $(".ui-btn-icon-notext.ui-icon-delete").addClass("ui-btn-right");
});
```